# About Inserting Details into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have  a problem i.e 
I have a table called structure and home
If i insert the details in home page the id of the inserted row should store in structure table. But the problem is the id in home table is primary key and auto increment so i will not give the id manually now i want the id to store in structure how too get it immediately after inserting..

Please Help Me

`HOME` TABLE

- id int(4) primary key auto increment,
- content text;

`STRUCTURE` TABLE

- elementId int(4) primary key auto increment,
- id int(4);

Comment: http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: If you use mysql_*, [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Thanks @Truth Good Information It Worked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PDO (which you should be using), you can use **[`PDO::lastInsertedId()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)** to 
get the latest ID which was inserted into the database.